# How do I prevent the address bar from showing when following remote links in Rails 3 on an iOS device?

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, mobile-safari

I have a very simple Rails 3.1 list application targeted for webkit, and I want a list item "completed" animation to be the first priority when a user touches/clicks an item.

I first implemented this with a jQuery `.ajax()` call to my Rails route (e.g. /lists/1/items/1/complete), so I called the animation method first, followed by the ajax call to the Rails action/route. This worked great on my iPhone and iPad.

I decided I wanted to change this to "proper" `link_to ... :remote => true` tags. I kept the animation call on the page, and let Rails fire the update in the background.

The problem is that now when I touch an item to complete it on an iOS device, **the address bar comes down at the top for a second, then disappears.** This is pretty distracting, and with the jQuery `.ajax()` call, this never happened - the item would do its animation, the update would happen in the background, and the user could just keep completing items with no distractions.

Does anyone know why this is happening when I use the Rails `link_to ... :remote => true` tags? Is there some option I'm missing or a workaround for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar a few years ago and I used a little hack that I noticed the Gmail mobile site do.  Basically, they just moved the viewport down onLoad so that it was "hidden" when you looked at it.

I used something like this.

```
<body onload="setTimeout(function() { window.scrollTo(0, 1) }, 200);">

 body of the website ....

</body>
```

I haven't tried this recently and not sure if it works with the new mobile webkit but its worth a shot.

Let me know if you need anything else,

Kent

Comment: Just tried this quick Google search and it looks like this might be the best way to do it still. http://www.google.ca/search?aq=2&oq=hide+address+bar+in+safari&ix=hcb&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=hide+address+bar+in+safari+mobile